# Move entry from one form to another

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a couple of forms where I'd like to consolidate the entries into one.

How can I move an entry on one form to another?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not have the ability to move an entry out of one form, and into another form.